# Is it possible to exclude "this" from Type Inference in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, generics, type-inference, generic-constraints

I have the code below as a generic function to get all parents in a Tree type of structure.

When I use it in a class though, I'm getting a Type Error.

```
type GetParentFunc<T> = (x:T)=>T;


function getAllParents<T>(obj:T, getParent:GetParentFunc<T>)
{
    let result:T[] = [];

    let parent = getParent(obj);

    while ( parent != null )
    {
        result.push( parent );
        parent = getParent(parent);
    }

    return result;
}

class Category
{
    parent:Category;

    // doesn't work
    parentsBroken = () =>
    {
        return getAllParents(this, x => this.parent);
    }

    // works
    parentsFixed = () =>
    {
        return getAllParents<Category>(this, x => this.parent);
    }
}
```

`T` is getting filled in with `this` - and I get the following error about the x => x.parent argument.

```
Type 'Category' is not assignable to type 'this'.
```

This is easily fixable like:

```
getAllParents<Category>(this, x => x.parent)
getAllParents(this as Category, x => x.parent)
```

But I am a visual noise minimalist, and would rather spend some time so I can get rid of this noise for the foreseeable future.

Is there a way to exclude the `this` Type from a generic?

Like:

```
export function getAllParents<T exclude this>(obj:T, getParent:Func<T>)
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wgK8bw) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: that works, super!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of looking at this is that in `getAllParents(obj, getParent)`, it's possible for `getParent` to return something *wider* than its input type, and that it's this wider type you want to see as an output.  The [`this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) in TypeScript is essentially "the current class type whatever it happens to be" (which is implemented as an "implicit" [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameter).  But you wanted `Category`, the type returned by `x => x.parent`.

So we can rewrite `getAllParents` to explicitly account for this; `obj` is of type `T`, and `getParent` accepts a `T`, but it returns a `U` which is wider than `T`.  Which means `T` should be [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) as `T extends U`:

```
export function getAllParents<T extends U, U>(
    obj: T, getParent: (x: T) => U) {
    let result: U[] = [];

    let parent = getParent(obj);

    while (parent != null) {
        result.push(parent);

        parent = getParent(obj);
    }

    return result;
}
```

That compiles cleanly, and now your usage looks like:

```
parents = () => {
    return getAllParents(this, x => x.parent);
    //function getAllParents<this, Category>(obj: this, getParent: (x: this) => Category): Category[]        
}
```

so `T` is inferred as `this`, and `U` is inferred as `Category`, and the output is `Category[]` as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgGYFcB2BjOBLKaEDmIcAggDZkAKAhjCGnAM4A8AKguHPQCaMICqAGgEA+ABTAEUhFABGAKwBcCVsKJwadBsrFhlrAJQIAvCIFGA3pOlliCOoxRk4y-gG0AuiYSeA3MGspW0QIWnpEY0JiTXCxOXkDf0CEAHcAC2xbBDFQrUQAQki0JzJLZOl7EEdnADoIFEY0nLCGRICKitzw73UYhjiFNoqAX3bpOjgUGHwHJzh-UeAMMmpGPgBhai4CWABPBCtOlpcETe297zQQFNOtkB2YXbEh6S6GPkjnkzNDjqkJqb4dTkKjHRhiOAZRjCMDfBBgOrHF5-AD0KNQmBweCipAofSYzEh2Ght3Oj3E8WURJJvWOOj0CGpRlMpPuewMyjObMenj+UmSo2GQA)

Comment: great and extended answer! thanks!

Comment: aii, wait I put an error in my code - the second is getParent(parent) - that doesn't compile for me, but if I cast it to `as T` it works - might be a bit ugly, but for me it works!